# How do I append PostGIS commands to the system path?

Tags: postgis-2.0

I'd like to be able to call psql instead of having to put in the full path everytime.  I went into Environment Variables through My Computer and added the path to the semi-colon separated list, but still no luck.

I'm sure this is easy, just haven't dealt much with Windows commands.

Comment: You will need to send the DB and Password - this can be done via environment variable. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216432/windows-psql-command-line-is-there-a-way-to-allow-for-passwordless-login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Mapperz, you anticipated one question ahead.  I finally came across this half way down the [OpenGeo resources site](http://workshops.opengeo.org/stack-intro/postgis.html).

`set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\OpenGeo\OpenGeo Suite\pgsql\8.4\bin`